# 39TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function .ajaxform

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

Im trying to do an image upload with a preview function, with the help of ajaxForm.
Everything works, except the preview part and I get the error message:

```
39TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#imageform").ajaxForm(
{
target: "#preview"
})')
```

The code I'm using is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function() {
        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: "#preview"
        }).submit();
    });
});
</script>



<div id="preview">
Upload image
</div>
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
<input type="file"name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
</div>
```

Anyone that might know what the problem is?
Would really appreciate the help!

Thank you

/C

Comment: It could be that the plugin doesn't `return this`

Comment: Any suggestions how I can check that out?The plugin code looks like this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1829119/jquery.form.js

Comment: According to their documentation, `ajaxForm` is chainable, but also, since you want to immediately submit the form, I think you might want to use `ajaxSubmit` and send the same options

Comment: I tried using this: $("#imageform").ajaxSubmit(
{
target: "#preview"
}(); but it did not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I managed to clear all the errors. But the image I upload still doesn't preview.